# Pooled Model significant, panel model not significant

Tags: generalized-linear-model, panel-data, pooling

I am running normal `glm` model in `R`, where

```
glm(outcome ~ treatment + covariates, family=binomial(logit), data=data)
```

Pooled model with fixed effects of panel wave shows a significant effect of treatment on the outcome variable. However, when I conduct the same model by panel wave, `glm(outcome ~ treatment + covariates, family=binomial(logit), data=wave1)` the significance of treatment effect disappears.

I would like to know what does this mean. How should I interpret the effect of treatment in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

1. The treatment effect is homogenous. The coefficients from the pooled and per-wave models are similar, but the latter are insignificant because the estimates are less precise (due to the smaller sample size). $p$-values are functions of the sample size, so a $p$-value changing when the sample size changes isn't surprising.
2. The treatment effect is heterogeneous. The coefficients from the pooled and per-wave models do not match because the treatment effect actually differs between waves.

You don't say anything about the magnitude of your coefficients in relation to the standard errors.

Perhaps you should consider a multi-level model in which there are wave-specific effects and wave-specific treatment effects. You could then test whether the model with wave-specific treatment effects is a better fit for your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I explored the data more in depth, and it seems like the treatment effect is heterogeneous --- its effect differs between waves.